# Are WF and WCF technologies or languages?

Tags: .net

I want to know whether Windows Workflow Foundation and Windows Communication Foundation in .Net are languages or technologies. Basically they are Foundation but what are they really?

Answer (score 3):

From the great and one click away [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation)- 
`The Windows Communication Foundation (or WCF) is a runtime and a set of APIs (application programming interface) in the .NET Framework for building connected, service-oriented applications.`

Answer (score 0):

In short: they are not languages. I highly suggest you start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) and then work your way over to [here](http://www.google.com/?q=WF+and+WCF+and+.net).